# phaser.js, javascript, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm a beginner on Phaser.js and Javascript. I'm making a game and I've a bug that I can't figure how to fix it.
I think I can explain why it is happening : when i debug the phisics group SpritesPlatform shows that it's not undefined .. I don't know why ..

here the file where I've the bug ( I can't put the entire application here cause there's many files, but the problem concerns this file only, and the sprites are loaded in another file ).

file game.js (main.js)

```
MyGame.Game = function (game) {
    this.game;      //  a reference to the currently running game (Phaser.Game)
    this.add;       //  used to add sprites, text, groups, etc (Phaser.GameObjectFactory)
    this.load;      //  for preloading assets (Phaser.Loader)
    this.stage;     //  the game stage (Phaser.Stage)
    this.state;     //  the state manager (Phaser.StateManager)
    this.world;     //  the game world (Phaser.World)
    this.physics;   //  the physics manager (Phaser.Physics)
};

MyGame.Game.prototype = {

    init: function () {

            this.game.renderer.renderSession.roundPixels = true;
            this.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
            this.physics.arcade.gravity.y = 800;

    },

    create: function () {

        // background color bleu
        this.stage.backgroundColor = 0x479cde;

        //add sprites into physics group
        SpritesPlatform = this.game.add.physicsGroup();
        a = SpritesPlatform.create(0, 150, 'sprite');
        a.scale.setTo(0.2, 0.2);
        b = SpritesPlatform.create(79, 187, 'sprite2');
        b.scale.setTo(0.2, 0.2);
        c = SpritesPlatform.create(300, 100, 'sprite3');
        c.scale.setTo(0.4, 0.4);

        SpritesPlatform.setAll('body.allowGravity', false);
        SpritesPlatform.setAll('body.immovable', true);
        SpritesPlatform.setAll('body.velocity.x', 150);

        //test to see if the group contains the sprites
        /*var i = 0;
        for (var i = 0, len = SpritesPlatform.children.length; i < len; i++) {
            console.log(SpritesPlatform.children[i]);
        }*/

        //debug
        console.log(this.game.SpritesPlatform); // prints undefined .. why???


  },

    // repeat the mouvement of the sprites when it crosses the screen
    wrapSprites: function (SpritesPlatform) {

           if (SpritesPlatform.body.velocity.x < 0 && SpritesPlatform.x <= -160)
            {
                SpritesPlatform.x = 800;
            }

        },


    update: function () {

        console.log(this.game.SpritesPlatform); // prints undefined  also of course... ?? why??
        //the error is here ... if i put this in comment the code will display the board and the sprite ...
        //this.game.SpritesPlatform.forEach(this.game.wrapSprites, this.game);
    },
};
```

the problem is in the update function in the line : //this.game.SpritesPlatform.forEach(this.game.wrapSprites, this.game);

It looks like the SpritesPlatform is undefined, and i don't understand why and what i'm missing.

thank u for any help.

Comment: You've never actually define `this.game`. In the constructor try: `this.game = game`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first create the group, you have to declare it like that:

```
this.SpritesPlatform = this.game.add.physicsGroup();
```

and whenever you want to refer to this group you can do it with `console.log(this.SpritesPlatform)`

**Edit:**

You don't actually have to do anything like that

```
MyGame.Game = function (game) {
  this.game;      //  a reference to the currently running game (Phaser.Game)
  this.add;       //  used to add sprites, text, groups, etc (Phaser.GameObjectFactory)
  this.load;      //  for preloading assets (Phaser.Loader)
  this.stage;     //  the game stage (Phaser.Stage)
  this.state;     //  the state manager (Phaser.StateManager)
  this.world;     //  the game world (Phaser.World)
  this.physics;   //  the physics manager (Phaser.Physics)
};
```

All those properties are readily accessible, so you can just use them wherever you want inside a state. This should work just fine:

```
MyGame.Game = function () {
};
```

Comment: thank u for answering me, but that doesn't solve the bug, I mean  when i put this this.SpritesPlatform , the code desn't  run and gives me the same error, even if i don't include the line in the update() that gives me the bug, am i missing something else please??

Comment: i'm getting this error specifically : Uncaught ReferenceError: SpritesPlatform is not defined, in this line : a = SpritesPlatform .create(0, 150, 'sprite');

Comment: i fixed it finally by adding "this" everywhere that "SpritesPlatform " is used...

Comment: Have you changed  `SpritesPlatform....` to `this.SpritesPlatform` everywhere? Check [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNMOew) to see what i mean **Edit:** ok nice!